# counting combinations in excel and use as size in bubble chart

Tags: excel, charts

In my analysis spreadsheet in Excel, I am scoring stakeholders on power to implement change (P) and their interest in the change (I) of our project. I then want to present that as a bubble chart (10 by 10) where the number of unique combinations (e.g. P-I => 10-8 = 3, number of times this combination is scored = 3) are represented by the size of the bubble on a given point (X=10, Y=8, Size=3).

I have the score in a table including an additional column for the combination (concat P&"-"&I) that I count in pivot table.

This approach does not appear work. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: you lost me ;-)

Comment: Is my question not clear?